# .htaccess- RewriteCond causes redirections

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

On my wordpress website I found that I need to strip `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d` in order to make a plugin i'm using to work correctly.
My .htaccess file is as follows :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php  [L]
</IfModule>
```

Once I strip `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d`
from the .htaccess file, some pages, for example site.com/wp-admin are returning 302 with Location to the exact same page, so there's a loop of 302 requests to site.com/wp-admin.

I'd like to know what might cause this problem.

**EDIT**:
Why did I remove this condition from the .htaccess file ?
Before removing it, the $_SERVER array contained the following values :

```
["REQUEST_URI"]=>
  string(29) "/best/?sort_by=post_title_asc"
["REDIRECT_URL"]=>
  string(10) "/403.shtml"
["QUERY_STRING"]=>
  string(0) ""
```

And the plugin which expected query string did not work correctly.
After removing it, the $_SERVER array contained the following values instead :

```
["QUERY_STRING"]=>
  string(22) "sort_by=post_title_asc"
 ["REQUEST_URI"]=>
  string(29) "/best/?sort_by=post_title_asc"
["QUERY_STRING"]=>
  string(22) "sort_by=post_title_asc"
```

And the plugin worked just fine.

Comment: You need to post your full .htaccess. there is not enough info to help you. And also the reason why the plugin requires removal of that condition.

Comment: @PanamaJack, thanks for the reply, I've now edited the post.